# Laravel 5.1 get variable from pretty URL to Request object

Tags: php, laravel, get

I have a controller method in Laravel 5.1 that takes both GET and POST requests.

There are some variables I have to pass in to that method.

So I'd pass the variable in like this:

```
http://localhost/<methodName>/<var1 value>/<var2 value>
```

I'd like Laravel's Request object to be populated with those variables.

Of course I can do:

```
http://localhost/<MethodName>?var1=var1_value&var2=var2_value
```

But I'd like to keep the pretty url mentioned before and still be able to populate Request object.

```
public function methodName(Request $request)
{
    dd($request);
}
```

This return an empty array.

Yes, I can do something like:

```
public function methodName(Request $request, $var1= "", $var2 = "")
{
    dd($var1." ".$var2);
}
```

This will return the variables but I'd really like to have the Request object populated if possible.

The route I'm using is:

```
 Route::match(['get', 'post'],
 '/<method-name>/{<var1_value>?}/{<var2_value>?}/{<var3_value>?}',
 '<ControllerName>@<methodName>');
```

Post variables are not a problem.

Comment: What do you mean by " Laravel's Request object to be populated" ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your controller, use route() function on $request object.

```
$request->route('var1');
```

Of course the name of parameter must match what you define in your routes.php

```
Route::get('your/route/{var1}/{var2}','YourController@method');
```

Comment: Not exactly what I was looking for but this does provide a way to retrieve the variable from Request object. It does work. I have chained a where method in my route call and I could validate the route too. I guess this will work. Thanks a lot Carter.